# Is Python's SOAPpy library threadsafe?

Tags: python, soap, thread-safety

How thread safe is the SOAPpy library for Python?  I'm finding the documentation non-existent and no mention of thread safety (for or against) anywhere.

Specifically, **can threads share a SOAPpy.SOAPProxy object, calling different RPCs**?  e.g,

```
client = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy(url)
thread1: client.MyFunc()
thread2: client.MyFunc()
```

Without ill-effects?

Additionally, **is the construction of the proxy objects expensive**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SOAPpy.SOAPProxy` doesn't appear to be thread-safe at first glance. In the version 0.12.0 `__call` method, there is an assignment (`Client.py` line 360):

```
        r, self.namespace = self.transport.call(self.proxy, m, ns, sa,
                                                encoding = self.encoding,
                                             http_proxy = self.http_proxy,
                                                config = self.config)
```

So if `client.MyFunc()` is invoked from 2 different threads, they will create separate connections but will both assign a value to the `self.namespace` attribute.

On the plus side, constructing an instance of SOAPProxy for each thread should be quite efficient.  I was able to create 100 instances in ~1ms on a virtual machine, which should be small compared to a SOAP request round-trip time.

Comment: Hmm, I tried tracing that "namespace" parameter around.  It seems that if its set to `None` in the constructor, it stays None throughout the lifetime.  Otherwise, it ends up changing it to something based on the  response (the transport.call() function).

So, it looks threadsafe if you don't specify a namespace.

Comment: That said, with how cheap it is to create a proxy, I'll probably just do it per-thread anyways, rather than chasing down strange code paths looking for potential thread safety issues.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't care about the namespace (and assuming it's not used elsewhere inside the client for anything useful) you may be okay. I posted proxy-creation times measured on my local Ubuntu vm, and found creation time of around 10 microseconds, so you can create about 100k proxies per second, so they're pretty cheap. I'd create one per thread and reuse them, as they're just used as factories for the real HTTP connections.